# Play audio from background script in chrome extention manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

In manifest v2 i used to play audio from background script like this

```
new Audio(url)
```

But in manivest v3 same script is showing error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Audio is not defined

How to Play audio from background script(which is changed to service worker in v3) in chrome extention?

Comment: ManifestV3 has killed this feature. Let's hope it'll be implemented later, see  https://crbug.com/1131236.

Answer (score 18):

## New Solution With Offscreen Documents

It's not currently possible to play or capture media directly in service workers because they don't have access to DOM APIs.

[*Offscreen documents*](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) is out for Chrome version 109, so here is my solution based on the [api test file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bded81b1c689a234be93e3e3b4c5148f9d16842d/chrome/browser/extensions/api/offscreen/offscreen_apitest.cc) from Chromium. Because code on an offscreen document has access to the needed API, you need to open one and use message passing to play the sound from there. This solution is far more elegant than the older one, which utilized a visible popup window for the same reason.

To play a sound in the service worker, call the `playSound()` function with the appropriate parameters as shown below.
If you don't play sounds for 30 seconds, the offscreen document will be closed automatically because of the "lifetime enforcement".

`manifest.json`

```json
...
"permissions": ["offscreen"]
...
```

`background.js`

```js
/**
 * Plays audio files from extension service workers
 * @param {string} source - path of the audio file
 * @param {number} volume - volume of the playback
 */
async function playSound(source = 'default.wav', volume = 1) {
    await createOffscreen();
    await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ play: { source, volume } });
}

// Create the offscreen document if it doesn't already exist
async function createOffscreen() {
    if (await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) return;
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: 'offscreen.html',
        reasons: ['AUDIO_PLAYBACK'],
        justification: 'testing' // details for using the API
    });
}
```

`offscreen.html`

```html
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

`offscreen.js`

```js
// Listen for messages from the extension
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    if ('play' in msg) playAudio(msg.play);
});

// Play sound with access to DOM APIs
function playAudio({ source, volume }) {
    const audio = new Audio(source);
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.play();
}
```

**Note:** The offscreen API is relatively new, so some users might not yet have the minimum required version of Chrome (109) to support it. If you care about such users, you could use the older solution as a polyfill by checking if `chrome.offscreen` is undefined.

**One last thing:** You should update the justification property for creating the offscreen document. It's required, but not yet used. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/#type-CreateParameters) says the following:

> justification
>
> A developer-provided string that explains, in more detail, the need for the background context. The user agent *may* use this in display to the user.

## Original answer

As written in the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#audio_vidio):

> It's not currently possible to play or capture media directly in a
> service worker. In order for a Manifest V3 extension to leverage the
> web's media playback and capture capabilities, the extension will need
> to create a window environment using either chrome.windows.create() or
> chrome.tabs.create(). Once created, the extension can use message
> passing to coordinate between the playback document and service
> worker.

Until they do something about this, (hopefully, they eventually will - considering the usage of "currently" in their article) here is a quick workaround:

`audio.html`

```html
<link href='icon.png' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'>
<title>Notification</title>
<script src="audio.js"></script>
<style> :root { color-scheme: light dark }</style>
```

`audio.js`

```js
resizeTo(0, 0);
onload = () => {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    let audio = new Audio(urlParams.get('src'));
    audio.volume = urlParams.get('volume');
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(close, urlParams.get('length'));
}
```

`background.js` (the service worker)

```js
function playSound() {
    let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('audio.html');

    // set this string dynamically in your code, this is just an example
    // this will play success.wav at half the volume and close the popup after a second
    url += '?volume=0.5&src=success.wav&length=1000';

    chrome.windows.create({
        type: 'popup',
        focused: true,
        top: 1,
        left: 1,
        height: 1,
        width: 1,
        url,
    })

}
```

Once `playSound()` gets called, it will create a popup that will play the sound. It's a good idea to set the popup's icon to your extension's icon with the `<link>` tag so your users will know where the popup came from.

Note that `audio.js` must be linked from a separate file. Otherwise, you would receive an inline script policy violation error.

### Further ideas

If you play sounds while sending toast notifications with the [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/) API, You might want to move your popup behind the notification. An easy way to do that is to create the popup in the bottom right corner with: `top: 99999, left: 99999` Then in your javascript: `moveTo(window.screenX - 100, window.screenY);`

Alternatively, you could turn the popup itself into the toast notification.

### Update #1

Seems like there is some work being done on a feature called *offscreen documents* for MV3. With this new API, extensions will be able to open limited, offscreen documents having access to DOM APIs.

More info is in the [proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b-I-vXq2h7OFFmus78jZXIWcKilKJLKLeGplnY9wt7k/edit).
And [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339382) you can track its development.

However, this won't be the final solution. As stated in the proposal, long term, Chromium intends to support many of these capabilities directly within extension service workers.