# Chrome extensions: background.html to background.js for Manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I've had a working Google Chrome extension that was using Manifest v2 file where the "background" field was set as follows:

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
```

background.html was simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <audio controls="" name="media" src="http://stream.from_somewhere.com:8000/now.mp3" id="myplayer"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

However, Chrome extensions now require [Manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/) with [service_worker background parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#manifest):

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

How would I convert my existing background.html to background.js?

Comment: AFAIK, even in manifest v2, there was nothing like `page` for a background script. It was always `scripts`.

Comment: Nope, there was "page".

Comment: [chrome.offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) might be what you need.

Comment: Thomas, would you give a more detailed answer considering I'm a begginer in all things web or javascript related.

Comment: I've never used chrome.offscreen to play audio, so if you want code to copy & paste into your extension, I can't help you. But you might want to read [Play audio from background script in chrome extention manifest v3 > New Solution With Offscreen Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437180/play-audio-from-background-script-in-chrome-extention-manifest-v3/70402480#70402480)