# Chrome Extension V3 offscreen audio not working due to "Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to make sound play once a message is sent from the service-worker. I have been following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437180/play-audio-from-background-script-in-chrome-extention-manifest-v3) but it always provides the below errors, alternating:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
"Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated."

Could someone point me in the right direction? I assume I am missing something obvious. Thank you in advance!

## content.js

```
// Function to check if the conditions are met and click the button
function checkAndClick() {
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "playSoundPlease"});
}

setInterval(checkAndClick, 5000);
```

## offscreen.html

```
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

## offscreen.js

```
// Listen for messages from the extension
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    if (message.type === "playSoundPlease2") playAudio(msg.play);
});

// Play sound with access to DOM APIs
function playAudio({ source, volume }) {
    const audio = new Audio(source);
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.play();
}
```

## background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if (message.type === "playSoundPlease") {
      playSound();
    }
  });

async function playSound(source = 'notification.mp3', volume = 1) {
    await createOffscreen();
    await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ play: { source, volume }, type: "playSoundPlease2" });
}

// Create the offscreen document if it doesn't already exist
async function createOffscreen() {
    if (await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) return;
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: 'offscreen.html',
        reasons: ['AUDIO_PLAYBACK'],
        justification: 'testing' // details for using the API
    });
}
```

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Sound Test Manifest V3",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "None",
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*"],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["notification.mp3"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],  
  "permissions": [               
      "offscreen"              
    ]
}
```

I tried adding Audio and various other permissions, async lambda functions but am not able to get this to work.

Comment: I think background.js is sending the message before offscreen.js can receive it.

Comment: The error comes from an orphaned content script after you reload the extension. You need to stop your timer via clearInterval using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345) as an example. Second problem is that you need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension (you'll do it anyway to deal with the orphaned script) or reload all tabs, which is usually a bad idea as it may lose the state in an endless feed on sites like facebook. P.S. Why don't you play the audio in the content script? There's no need for the offscreen document.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, issue was

```
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

instead of `scripts/offscreen.js`, missed that.